# Calculate Multiple Correlation Between Several Products

Tags: r, statistics, bigdata, correlation, data-science

I Want to get the correlation between several Items which regarding to the historical Orders and sales and i want to do that to create a recommendation model for every new order (recommend the products depending on the correlation between the selected product and others) , So that i have an Idea to get this correlation by Create a query which pivoting my data to get every Order with the total of quantity of its items and then calculate the correlation between item.
I Already Attached an Excel Sheet Has a sample data for my case.
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B406d2ytAgbjR0t4V2VUVFVWNlE/view?usp=sharing).
[image]
"the numbers in the columns of products is the total of the quantity in every order for every product >> As Example the order of 131245 was has 1.96 of the product 11 and 3.91 of 27 and so on" i want to get the correlation between all products > the correlation depends on the orders and the items in it.
Is this Idea is Useful to get the correlation or i should use different value to calculate it ?
Any One have an idea about that ?

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible* by first reading about [minimal, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Then edit your question and add some sample data and code you've tried. Note that SO specifically calls ["off-topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question: (1) suggesting software or libraries, and (2) without specific problems with programming code.

Comment: Your question is getting better, thank you. You may find many volunteers here are not willing to download an arbitrary file from your google drive (especially when it is not at all like the image of data you presented). Quickly-answered <tag>r</tag> questions on SO tend to have data we can "consume" (easily copy/paste), as demoed in the links I offered earlier (e.g., `dput(head(x))`). Otherwise you're just having an academic discussion about theoreticals ... still not quite on-topic for SO. Perhaps [SW Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you to think what the correlation must be. If product A and B are always brought together, then the correlation would be 1. But what do you want to do if sometimes only product A is bought and sometimes both A and B? There is not one good code for this problem

Comment: the degree of the correlation between two items dependence on the frequency of getting A & B at the same order, If there's no order has A & B at the same time then the correlation between them = 0 , And the Negative Correlation will be to the case of purchasing A causes Negative chance for Purchasing B.

Comment: I think the best way to do it is to use booleans, `TRUE` if it is a positive number and `FALSE` if there is no number (so the product is not in an order). If you look at product A, you need to look at only the `TRUE` values, if, let say, B is half of the time `TRUE` then your correlation is 0.5. So you need to divide the number of True values of A by the number of True values of B. Note that the correlation between A and B is not the same as B and A with this method.

Comment: Its a good idea but how to apply it on many items at same time and get the correlation between every item to every item ? i have more than 200 items and there's another cases i will have more this number so i need a way to apply this idea on my data, if i replaced the value of quantity with 1 or 0 then the correlation will be 0 or 1 only so i need some  ways to handle the value which i should use.

Comment: Perhaps there is a standard function in R for this, but I the best way is, I think, to make a couple of for loops. `for A in products`, `for i in orders`, `if A[i]==TRUE`, `for B in products`, `if B[i]==TRUE`. This way you can count how many products other than A are bought together with A. And then you can divide by how many A is bought. Hope this will work